# $10^n+1$ as a product of consecutive primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am interested to know the examples or the systematic rule whether $10^n+1$ is a product of consecutive primes.

For example,

when $n=1$,

we have $10^1+1=11$ is a product of a single prime 11. So, a True example.

When $n=2$,

we have $10^2+1=101$ is a product of a single prime 101. So, a True example.

When $n=3$,

we have $10^3+1=1001$ is a product of a product of consecutive primes $7*11*13$. So, a True example.

When $n=4$,

we have $10^4+1=10001$ is NOT a product of a product of consecutive primes $73*137$. So, a False example.

Are there more examples or the systematic rule whether $10^n+1$ is a product of consecutive primes?

Comment: It is unlikely that there are more examples (except when $10^n+1$ is prime)

Comment: Although technical a single prime is a "product of consecutive primes", such a formulation should only be used for composite numbers. In this sense, we would only have one example. But even if we allow single primes, no primes of the form $10^n+1$ for $n\ge 3$ are known, and if one exists it must be extremely large! I agree with Hagen's comment that a further composite example is extremely unlikely as well, but a proof that there is no further example will probably be out of reach as well.

Comment: If you allow $n=0$ as well and a single prime, $10^0+1=2$ is another example.

Answer (score 5):

Using FactorInteger[] in mathematica you can try various values of n and see if they fit the pattern. I tried $n=21$ and $n=100$, neither one did.

(If you don't have mathematica, you can just enter "FactorInteger[number you want prime factorization of] into wolfram alpha).

Comment: Thanks, I will also like to see a general statement or pattern if there is, at least for some $n<25$.

Comment: I looked at all n<25. The pattern doesn't hold for any value you didn't mention.

Comment: +1, Can one prove that the pattern does not exist for any $n>3$?

Comment: I don't see how to do that. If no one has answered in three days, I'll stick a bounty on it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm finding that $11$ divides $10^n+1$ for all odd $n$. $7*11*13$ divides $10^n+1$ for odd $n$ divisible by $3$. But $17$ is a divisor only if $n$ is an odd multiple of $8$. Thus it seems $10^n+1$ is not a product of consecutive primes for odd $n>3$.  If even $n$ is an odd multiple of $2$, $101$ divides $10^n+1$, but $103$ seems to be a divisor only for odd $n$ in sequence $17,119,221...$. If even $n$ is an odd multiple of $4$, $73$ and $137$ are consecutive divisors of $10^n+1$, but they are not consecutive primes. If even $n$ is an odd multiple of $8$, as already noted, $17$ is a divisor, but not $13$, and $19$ is a divisor only if $n$ is an odd multiple of $9$. Thus it seems, for $n>3$, $10^n+1$ could be the product of consecutive primes only if $16$ divides $n$. Is there a way to rule out these $n$ as well? For $n=16$ or any odd multiple of $16$, $10^n+1$ contains $353*449*641*1409*69857$, which are not consecutive primes. For $n=32$ and its odd multiples, $10^n+1$ contains $19841*976193*6187457*834427406578561$, again not consecutive primes. Thus if $10^n+1$ is not the product of consecutive primes when $n$ is a given power of $2$, then it is not the product of consecutive primes for any odd multiple of that power of $2$. This shortens the search among the even $n$ remaining.